# Use command substitution with backticks inside subprocess.call()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

As long as I have the appropriate programs installed - `fortune` is not installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04 - I can use the following command to have my computer's speech-to-text functionality tell me to get back to work, and then read me an inspirational quote from [`fortune`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)):

```
spd-say "get back to work and remember `fortune`"
```

Here I am using command substitution with backticks to add the result of calling the `fortune` command to the string of text to be read. Within Python, I can use `subprocess` to do this:

```
subprocess.call(['spd-say', 'get back to work'])
```

However, command substitution with backticks doesn't appear to work here:

```
subprocess.call(['spd-say', 'get back to work and remember `fortune`'])
```

In this case, I will hear: "get back to work and remember fortune". I assume this is because `subprocess` is passing a single-quoted string, and this kind of command substitution only works within double-quoted strings.

I have tried various solutions, including using double quotes, double quotes inside single quotes, but I think it is still passing a single-quoted string with double quotes inside rather than a double-quoted string.

I have also tried writing the entire command as a single string, and breaking it up using `shlex.split()`:

```
import shlex
command = 'spd-say "get back to work and remember `fortune`"'
command_args = shlex.split(command)
```

But this gives me:

```
['spd-say', 'get back to work and remember `fortune`']
```

Again, no double quotes.

Is there any way to force wrap a single argument in double quotes (if that is indeed the problem), or otherwise pipe the output of the `fortune` command to `spd-say` in the way described above using `subprocess.call()`?

Comment: As an aside -- I'd strongly suggest avoiding `shlex.split()` in favor of hardcoding your lists: As a human, you know *exactly* how you want them parsed, so you might as well pass them through in that form (also, it means the reader only needs to know *one* quoting syntax -- Python syntax -- vs two, Python and shell). The former approach makes it easy to get in trouble by doing something like `shlex.split("your-command --file=%s" % filename)`, which can expand out into multiple arguments if the filename contains spaces, vs `['your-command', '--file=%s' % filename]`, which is unambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expansion of command substitutions is a shell operation. Without `shell=True`, there *is* no shell involved in `subprocess` operations. That's highly desirable behavior in general: If you're passing filenames around as input, you don't want a filename containing `$(rm -rf $HOME)` (and yes, all those characters are legal in filenames on typical UNIX systems) to cause content to be deleted.

However, if you're *sure* you want command substitution to take place, that's a place where shell evaluation is desirable:

```
subprocess.call('spd-say "get back to work and remember $(fortune)"', shell=True)
```

...which is equivalent to to the following, *without* `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', 'spd-say "get back to work and remember $(fortune)"'])
```

---

Incidentally, if you pass an array with `shell=True`, only the first argument is parsed as a script (and thus has command substitutions and like expansions performed); other arguments are literal arguments which can be interpreted by the script itself:

```
subprocess.call(
  ['spd-say "$1 $(fortune)"',                     # this is a script
   "_",                                           # this is a literal for $0 in the script
   "get back to work, don't $(rm), and remember"  # this is a literal for $1 in the script
  ], shell=True)
```

The `$(rm)` isn't executed here because only the content in the first list element (`'spd-say "$1 $(fortune)"'`) is treated as script text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am aware of the security risks associated with using `shell=True`, which you give a good example of in your answer. However, I am wondering if, in a simple program like the one above (for arguments sake, if my script does nothing more than make that single `subprocess.call()` call), is there still a danger of misuse or exploitation? The only thing I can think of is if the `fortune` command got replaced with something malicious so that when `$(fortune)` gets run something bad happens, but that doesn't seem likely...

Comment: Excluding cases like shellshock, where you have other side-effects from shell execution, the primary risk is when you're substituting untrusted/unaudited content into the script argument itself. If the string ```spd-say "get back to work and remember `fortune`"``` is hardcoded in your software, you're perfectly fine; if you're concatenating something you got from the user, the filesystem, or otherwise a less-trusted source in generating it, by contrast, then you're in danger.

Comment: It's really very much the same kind of thing as SQL injection -- if you're generating SQL by concatenating or substituting in values, then you're at risk for injection attacks; if the only dynamic values are passed out-of-band in arguments and your query isn't doing anything unreasonable/unsafe with those values, then you're probably fine. Here, it's a question of whether it's the first argument -- the script itself -- that you're substituting values into, or if it's the subsequent arguments (which aren't interpreted as script text).

Comment: Thanks! All very helpful!